# Creating xml video sitemap

Tags: video, sitemap

can anyone help me? I want to create xml sitemap for videos but the url of the video file is stored in table.
Please tell me how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want to generate a sitemap automatically? What kind of table are you talking about? A database table? What do you mean by a 'video sitemap'? Are you talking about the Google extensions to the Sitemap protocol? The question is a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

You could try A1 Sitemap Generator. Be sure to follow the [video sitemap tutorial](http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/help/video-xml-sitemaps/) (i.e. remember to use the video sitemap presets.) If you still have problems, email/message or post your website URL here. It is hard to give a better answer without being able to see the URL.

(I have never heard anyone use the phrase the "video file is stored in table", but I imagine you actually mean the references to the video file? Do you mean the HTML table tag itself contains a reference to the video file? That would be quite unusual...)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear and I don't know which language you are using to achieve that, but since I had a similar question and I found the answer with asp.net, you can take a look at this solution.

[How to generate videoSiteMap with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45779878/4412698)